# Unable to launch Firefox: keeps on crashing

Tags: libraries, firefox

Unable to launch Firefox in CentOS 6. Installed package using `yum install firefox`.

It repeatedly shows this error,

> XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so:
>
> libvpx.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Couldn't load XPCOM.

How to rectify this error?

Comment: What is the output of `yum provides libvpx`??

Answer (score 7):

Although I am using Arch Linux and not CentOS, in case it helps, I encountered a similar issue with a recent upgrade of firefox (to 33.0.2). The problem looked like a simple case of dependencies that somehow did not get handled properly by the package manager.

The initial problem I encountered when I updated firefox and tried to start it was

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so:
libicui18n.so.54: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I tracked down that libicui18n.so.54 is in the `icu` (International Components for Unicode library) package, so I updated that package. I then tried to start `firefox` and got

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so:
/usr/lib/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.16.2' not found (required by /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so)
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

So, I tracked down that libnss3.so is in the `nss` (Mozilla Network Security Services) package, so I updated that package too.

Then everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Archlinux too, I got the similar error after upgrading firefox:

> XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so:
>   /usr/lib/libssl3.so: version `NSS_3.28' not found (required by /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so)
>   Couldn't load XPCOM.

I've updated the next following packages:

```
pacman -S nss zlib sqlite
```

Then firefox works!.

Answer (score 1):

I too am using Arch but haven't found any references to this same crash other than "updating the package" there is no "update for libxul.so" precisely, but some of the other error messages when trying to launch firefox from cli were helpful - I had to update "icu" as someone already mentioned, but Firefox still wouldn't launch but new error message pointed to "sqlite" out of date, updated it.

```
# pacman -Sy firefox firefox-adblock-plus firefox-noscript
# pacman -S icu lib32-icu harfbuzz-icu
# pacman -S sqlite lib32-sqlite
```

This seems to have solved problem, Firefox launches, slow to find websites but is working.

```
bill@arch-bill ~ % uname -a
Linux arch-bill 3.17.4-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 21 21:14:42 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to downgrade from Firefox 42 to 41 because I am reliant on an unsigned Firefox add-on. I am on Arch Linux. I got the similar error after downgrading the package.

I got the same error loading `libxul/so` due to a missing `libvpx.so.2` library file. I did, however, have `libvpx.so.3`.

My quick fix was to do this

```
# cd /usr/lib
# sudo ln -s libvpx.so libvpx.so.2
```

I couldn't downgrade `libvpx` because of other dependencies on it (`ffmpeg`). I know this is a nasty hack but it got me out of a, hopefully temporary, hole.

Just in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 0):

`libxul.so` should in your `firefox` folder.If not, that may be you extraction issue.

try: `yum install libvpx`